# Godot 3 - When body enters Area2D move Camera2D

Tags: godot, gdscript, body

I'm totally new to Godot 3 engine.
I want a game with static camera, so it can't smoothly follow player. I made an Area2D signal when_body_entered witch teleports main character to next area of map. Now I need to know how to move the camera (in Vector2 or just Y axis) when player enters the area.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

---

### Multiple cameras

Have multiple `Camera2D`. Then on the handler for `"body_entered"` signal of your `Area2D` you can set `Camera.current = true` for the `Camera2D` of the next room (areas of the map). And set `current` to `false` for the prior camera.

Alright, if you are going to have references to the cameras in your script, you may instead export some `NodePath`s for them. Something like this:

```
export var old_cam_path:NodePath
export var new_cam_path:NodePath

func when_body_entered(body:Node) -> void:
    get_node(new_cam_path).current = true
    get_node(old_cam_path).current = false

    # Also teleport the player character
```

Now, you should be able to select the old and the new camera in the inspector panel.

---

### Teleporting Camera

Alright, but we don't want to change cameras, we want to move the camera. Well, add some `Position2D` nodes to mark the position for the camera, and then we can do this:

```
export var cam_path:NodePath
export var cam_target_path:NodePath

func when_body_entered(body:Node) -> void:
    var cam := get_node(cam_path) as Camera2D
    var cam_target := get_node(cam_target_path) as Position2D
    cam.position = cam_target.position

    # Also teleport the player character
```

By the way, you can use the same approach to teleport the player character.

---

I'll also remind you that you can use the collision layers to filter what the `Area2D` detects. Also, a common approach is to use groups to discern between the bodies. You can add groups to nodes in the Node panel on the Groups tab. Then in code use `body.is_in_group("group_name")` to check.

---

### Traveling Camera

Another thing you can do with this is to *tween* over time the camera position instead of changing it instantly. To do that we can use a `Tween` node. Which in this case I will go ahead and create from code instead of adding it in the editor:

```
export var cam_path:NodePath
export var cam_target_path:NodePath

var tween:Tween

func _ready() -> void:
    tween = Tween.new()
    add_child(tween)

func when_body_entered(body:Node) -> void:
    var cam := get_node(cam_path) as Camera2D
    var cam_target := get_node(cam_target_path) as Position2D

    var seconds:float = 1.0
    tween.interpolate_property(cam, "position", cam.position, cam_target.position, seconds)
    tween.start()

    # Also teleport the player character
```

Here we are telling the `Tween` to move the `"position"` of the `camera`, from the current value of `camera.position` to the current value of `camera_target.position`, in the span of `seconds`.